# Как узнать с помощью какого GUI написана программа

Tags: gui, dll, exe, зависимости

Есть программа MSI Dragon Center: https://download.msi.com/uti_exe/nb/ap_DragonCenterv2.6.2003.2401_2.6.2003.2401_0x5fca1550.zip

C красивым интефейсом и кастомным окном (с прозрачными и полупрозрачными элементами и контролами).

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно через .exe узнать GUI на котором написана данная программа?

Моя цель - это создание нового современного GUI для своей программы., back-end у меня написан на C++, а GUI на убогом MFC.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложил скриншот Dependency Walker, какую директория нужно смотреть чтобы понять на чем написана GUI программы?

Answer (score 2):

Итак, Dependency Walker показывает mscoree.dll, значит, это .NET. Теперь запустите `ildasm.exe` из Visual Studio Command Prompt. Откройте в нем .exe, Manifest. Для Windows Forms там будет

```
.assembly extern System.Windows.Forms
```

Если это WPF, то:

```
.assembly extern PresentationFramework
.assembly extern System.Xaml
```

WinForms manifest:

[image: winforms]

WPF manifest:

[image: wpf]

Comment: Alex f, спасибо за помощь!!! Посмотрел с помощью утилиты ildasm файл манифеста и обнаружил там все три сборки: .assembly extern PresentationFramework, .assembly extern System.Xaml, .assembly extern System.Windows.Forms. Судя по всему GUI представляет из себя комбинацию WinForm/WPF на С#